# Outputting from loop to array in Matlab without overwriting

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, overwrite

I have a script to take the output of a simulink model and put this information in an array, such that each loop is written and then can be plotted/analysed etc. However on running the script I get the following:

```
test1

Outvs =

68.0000
68.0007
68.0430
68.0746

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in test1 (line 19)
output(sensv0) = Outvs;
```

My script is the following:

```
%Vectors/containers to store values%
%input = zeros(4,4);
output = zeros(4,4);

%INITIAL VELOCITY (v0)
%do a sensitivity analysis for different input values
for sensv0 = 85:88
    %step 1: define input value to variable
    v0 = sensv0;
    %step 2: run simulation
    sim('sldemo_absbrake');
    %step 3: look at graphs at t=0,5,10,15s for Vehicle Speed
    Outvs = getdatasamples(vs, [2,6,11,14]);
    %Display Outvs (troubleshooting)
    Outvs
    %input(sensv0) = v0;
    output(sensv0) = Outvs;
end
```

Comment: You put multiple samples into a single output field. If the output is a row(!) vector of length 4 (which I think based on your pre-allocation) you could try `output(sensv0-84,:) = Outvs;` Substracting 84 is necessary to access the indexes 1 up to 4, and the complete row is selected by the colon. If this does not work, just print the `Outvs` to the screen instead of assigning it to some subset of `output`. Then you can see how `Outvs` actually looks and based on that, you can think of a way to store that in a part of the `output` matrix properly.

Comment: Oops, I missed that you included the shape of `Outvs` in your question: its 4×1. So, this means that `output(:,sensv0-84) = Outvs;` should work. I am sure you can figure out why yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to handle such things.

1. If the size of `outvs` is constant, you can initialize a variable with the appropriate size:

   ```
   var=zeros([4,4])
   for k=85:88
       var(k-84, :)=outvs;
   end
   ```
2. the size of `outvs` varies, use a cell array (with curvy braces).

   ```
   for k=85:88
       var{k-84}=outvs;
   end
   ```